# CSS animation does not repeated

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to replace one container by another using CSS animation with 'scale' and 'rotate' as well as some small JavaScript. Everything works while you click first time button to show the second container and first time the second button to show the first contener back. After that contaners are switched (with the setup delay of 2s) but animation doesn't work anymore. You need to reload the page to make it working properly. The complete code (well, most of it) is here: https://jsfiddle.net/PPSkola/dmtbw6hz/ . I'd appreciate if somebody would be able to find the source of the problem. :)

```
<div id="prezentacija">Lorem ipsum</div>
<div id="informacija">Lorem ipsum</div>



/*  Animācijas apraksts  */
@keyframes zoomOutRotate {
    0% {transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    99% {transform: scale(0) rotate(360deg);}
}
@keyframes zoomInRotate {
    0% {transform: scale(1) rotate(0deg);}
    99% {transform: scale(0) rotate(-360deg);}
}



var kont1 = document.getElementById("prezentacija");
var kont2 = document.getElementById("informacija");
//
function paradiCitu() {
    kont1.style.animation = 'zoomOutRotate 2s';
    setTimeout(function(){
    kont1.style.visibility = "hidden"
    kont2.style.visibility = "visible";
}, 2000);}
//
function atpakal() {
    kont2.style.animation = 'zoomInRotate 2s';
    setTimeout(function(){
        kont2.style.visibility = "hidden"
        kont1.style.visibility = "visible";
        //window.location.reload();
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to clear animation style from element and give to him again

```
//  Atrodiet konteinerus dokumentā
var kont1 = document.getElementById("prezentacija");
var kont2 = document.getElementById("informacija");
//
//  Paslēpt pirmo ekrānu ar animāciju un parādīt otro
function paradiCitu() {
    //  Uzsākt animāciju
    kont1.style.animation = 'zoomOutRotate 2s';
    //  Paslēpiet vienu konteineru un parādiet citu pēc 2 sekundēm
    setTimeout(function(){
        kont1.style.visibility = "hidden"
        kont2.style.visibility = "visible";

 // this is what you need
  kont1.style.animation = "";
  kont2.style.animation = "";
  
    }, 2000);
}
//
//  Atgriezties atpakaļ
function atpakal() {
    //  Uzsākt animāciju
    kont2.style.animation = 'zoomInRotate 2s';
    //  Paslēpiet vienu konteineru un parādiet citu pēc 2 sekundēm
    setTimeout(function(){
        kont2.style.visibility = "hidden"
        kont1.style.visibility = "visible";
        //window.location.reload();
    }, 2000);
    
}
```

Comment: Oh mu god! It actually WORKS! Thanks a LOT, Ouchane! My first visit was SUCCESSFUL! I was sceptical in the beginning. I was wrong! Thanks again!